# Как реализовать календарь

Tags: android, java

Ребята, дайте совет новичку по разработке на Android

Мне нужна view календарь, которая при свайпе вверх уменьшается до недели и, естественно, становится меньше, а при свайпе влево (вправо) показывает следующий (предыдущий) месяц или неделю. Это всё должно работать плавно и дни должны быть кликабельны (можно выбрать день и посмотреть список дел на него). Какими средствами это можно реализовать?

Comment: Руки, голова? :-) Что вызывает сложности то?

Comment: github в помощь

Comment: Мешает незнание какие компоненты использовать? Fragment для этого подойдёт?

Comment: Вы с html версткой знакомы? Там много схожих принципов. Ну, и, просто почитайте про лайоту в android

Comment: Нет, я не знаком с html. Я никак не пойму как это реализовать и что использовать.

Comment: Начните с малого, полистайте учебники, посмотрите примеры.   
А то Вы сразу взялись за сложную задачу, но даже не знаете, как к ней приступить.

Comment: Есть приложение Cal, мне нужно что - то подобное.

Comment: @Roman_N1 - вы можете разобрать приложение `Cal` и посмотреть как оно там устроено, если конечно они код не обфусцировали.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите как реализовано [тут](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid)